# How to change a circles color in python, using iteration of a few selected colors, which changes with each button press, using Tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to design a **Mastermind** game, however I cannot seem to find a way to alter a circles color after it has been defined, in which it changes color each time a button is pressed, and iterates through a given list of colors. I also am looking for a way to store these colors within a list to be used later, and compared to a correct list of color circles.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import Tkinter
import math
import random
from Tkinter import *

class ResizingCanvas(Canvas):
    def __init__(self,parent,**kwargs):
        Canvas.__init__(self,parent,**kwargs)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_resize)
        self.height = self.winfo_reqheight()
        self.width = self.winfo_reqwidth()

    def on_resize(self,event):
        wscale = float(event.width)/self.width
        hscale = float(event.height)/self.height
        self.width = event.width
        self.height = event.height
        self.config(width=self.width, height=self.height)
        self.scale("all",0,0,wscale,hscale)

def main():

    root = Tk()

    myframe = Frame(root)
    myframe.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
    mycanvas = ResizingCanvas(myframe,width=300, height=425, highlightthickness=0)
    mycanvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)


    root.title('MasterMind!')

    dash_seperation_line = mycanvas.create_line(195,350,195,35, dash =(3,5))

    top_line = mycanvas.create_line(0,35,300,35)

    blue_layer = mycanvas.create_rectangle(0,425,425,325,fill = 'blue')

    title_text = mycanvas.create_text(150,15,text='MasterMind!')

    colors = ['red','green','blue']


    #Trying to cycle through these given colors
    color_iteration = color=itertools.cycle(('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow'))

    circles_list1 = []
    circles_list2 = []
    circles_list3 = []
    circles_list4 = []
    circles_list5 = []
    circles_list6 = []

    rectangles_list1 = []
    rectangles_list2 = []
    rectangles_list3 = []
    rectangles_list4 = []
    rectangles_list5 = []
    rectangles_list6 = []

    random_pick1 = random.choice(colors)
    random_pick2 = random.choice(colors)
    random_pick3= random.choice(colors)
    random_pick4 = random.choice(colors)

    answer_key = [random_pick4,random_pick3,random_pick2,random_pick1]

    r = 10
    x = 300
    y = 300

    #CIRCLES***
    for x in range(30,220,48):
        y = 50
        circle1 = mycanvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        circles_list1.append(circle1)
    c1_1 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list1[0])
    c2_1 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list1[1])
    c3_1 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list1[2])
    c4_1 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list1[3])


    for x in range(30,220,48):
        y = 100
        circle2 = mycanvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        circles_list2.append(circle2)
    c1_2 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list2[0])
    c2_2 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list2[1])
    c3_2 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list2[2])
    c4_2 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list2[3])

    for x in range(30,220,48):
        y = 150
        circle3 = mycanvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        circles_list3.append(circle3)
    c1_3 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list3[0])
    c2_3 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list3[1])
    c3_3 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list3[2])
    c4_3 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list3[3])

    for x in range(30,220,48):
        y = 200
        circle4 = mycanvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        circles_list4.append(circle4)
    c1_4 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list4[0])
    c2_4 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list4[1])
    c3_4 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list4[2])
    c4_4 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list4[3])

    for x in range(30,220,48):
        y = 250
        circle5 = mycanvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        circles_list5.append(circle5)
    c1_5 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list5[0])
    c2_5 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list5[1])
    c3_5 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list5[2])
    c4_5 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list5[3])

    for x in range(30,220,48):
        y = 300
        circle6 = mycanvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        circles_list6.append(circle6)
    c1_6 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list6[0])
    c2_6 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list6[1])
    c3_6 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list6[2])
    c4_6 =mycanvas.itemconfig(circles_list6[3],fill = current_color)


    #RECTANGLES***
    for x in range(210,300,25):
        y = 50
        rectangle1 = mycanvas.create_rectangle(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        rectangles_list1.append(rectangle1)
    r1_1 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list1[0])
    r2_1 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list1[1])
    r3_1 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list1[2])
    r4_1 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list1[3])
    for x in range(210,300,25):
        y = 100
        rectangle2 = mycanvas.create_rectangle(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        rectangles_list2.append(rectangle2)
    r1_2 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list2[0])
    r2_2 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list2[1])
    r3_2 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list2[2]) 
    r4_2 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list2[3])  
    for x in range(210,300,25):
        y = 150
        rectangle3 = mycanvas.create_rectangle(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        rectangles_list3.append(rectangle3)
    r1_3 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list3[0])
    r2_3 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list3[1])
    r3_3 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list3[2])
    r4_3 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list3[3])
    for x in range(210,300,25):
        y = 200
        rectangle4 = mycanvas.create_rectangle(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        rectangles_list4.append(rectangle4)
    r1_4 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list4[0])
    r2_4 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list4[1])
    r3_4 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list4[2])
    r4_4 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list4[3])
    for x in range(210,300,25):
        y = 250
        rectangle5 = mycanvas.create_rectangle(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        rectangles_list5.append(rectangle5)
    r1_5 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list5[0])
    r2_5 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list5[1])
    r3_5 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list5[2])
    r4_5 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list5[3])
    for x in range(210,300,25):
        y = 300
        rectangle6 = mycanvas.create_rectangle(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',fill='white')
        rectangles_list6.append(rectangle6)
    r1_6 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list6[0])
    r2_6 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list6[1])
    r3_6 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list6[2])
    r4_6 =mycanvas.itemconfig(rectangles_list6[3])

    print(answer_key)




    enter_button = Button(root,text='Enter')

    B1 = Button(root,text='B1') # Use these buttons to change each column of circles
    B2 = Button(root,text='B2')
    B3 = Button(root,text='B3')
    B4 = Button(root,text='B4')

    enter_button.place(relx=1, x=-125, y=380, anchor=NE)

    B1.place(relx=1, x=-246, y=325, anchor=NE)
    B2.place(relx=1, x=-199, y=325, anchor=NE)
    B3.place(relx=1, x=-150, y=325, anchor=NE)
    B4.place(relx=1, x=-101, y=325, anchor=NE)


    mycanvas.addtag_all("all")
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: We need a working example; you haven't given us enough details.  What is `mycanvas`?  What is `circles_list1`?  What is `Button`?  Are these things from some python package you're using?

Comment: okay added full code

Comment: That's much better, but now it's a bit much.  You want what's called a "minimal working example".  Note the "minimal".  As often as not, narrowing the problem down to the minimal amount needed to produce the problem actually helps you solve it.  But if you want other people to help you, you need to not waste their time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) to get item from iterator one by one:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> color_iteration = itertools.cycle(('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow'))
>>> next(color_iteration)
'blue'
>>> next(color_iteration)
'green'
>>> next(color_iteration)
'orange'
```

---

```
circle1 = mycanvas.create_oval(x-r, y-r, x+r, y+r, outline='#000000',      
                               fill=next(color_iteration))
```